# Count number of times value appears in particular column in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I would like to count the number of times a value appears in a column using Ms Access

eg.

```
Name  Count
Mike  2
Paul  1
Mike  2
Peter 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  COUNT(*) AS nbrof
FROM
  Table1
GROUP BY
  Name
```